# TYPO3 Image Manipulation removed after upgrade

Tags: typo3

After Upgrading my TYPO3 website from 8.2 to 8.7 version, the image manipulation has been removed from the news item images, how can I enable it or install it back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to new TCA requirements in TYPO3 8.7, this feature is not enabledin the current version of ext:news

I created this [pull request](https://github.com/georgringer/news/pull/362) with modified TCA which brings back the image cropping tool.

If you don't want to wait for the patch to be merged, you can easily apply it manually to your ext:news TCA. Feel free to update the pull request, if something is missing.